# Show that given conditions, the given distance function is not a metric

Tags: real-analysis

Let ${\cal C}[0,1]$ be the space of real valued continuous function on $[0, 1]$.  Fix $\psi \in {\cal C}[0,1]$ and define
$$\rho_{\psi}(f, g):= \int_0^1 \psi(x) |f(x) - g(x)| dx, \;\; f, g, \in {\cal C}[0,1].$$

Show that if $\psi(x) =  \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0, &  0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
x - \frac{1}{2}, & \frac{1}{2} < x \leq 1\\
\end{array}\right.$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, then $\rho_{\psi}$ is a not a metric on ${\cal C}[0,1]$.

I am stuck in this problem. It seems the Positive Definite and Symmetric properties are okay. I was trying to find a counterexample to the triangle inequality but to no avail. For instance, I was trying $f(x)=x^2$, $g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=x^3$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ and $g$ are functions that agree on $(1/2, 1]$, then $\rho_{\psi}(f, g)=0$ even if $f$ and $g$ are distinct.

Comment: Could you please elaborate. I am not seeing why its 0. Integration on [0,1/2] is definitely 0. What's happening in (1/2,1] even when f and g are distinct?

Comment: @Dom I am considering the case where $f(x)=g(x)$ for $x \in (1/2,1]$.

Comment: In that case, integration on (1/2,1] would be 0. That's the positive definite property. How does that show it isn't a metric?

Comment: @Dom: They are distinct functions, but they have zero distance

Comment: Could you give an example for f(x) and g(x)? I am still not getting it.